# difference between "rint" and "nearbyint"?

Tags: function, c++11, cmath

what is the difference between **rint** and **nearbyint**?
Will they give some different output in some cases?
If not, is there a difference in the concept of calculations?

Comment: From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nearbyint) "The only difference between std::nearbyint and std::rint is that std::nearbyint never raises FE_INEXACT."

Answer (score 2):

Since these are both C functions, we can check the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/rint) for both of these. An excerpt:

> The `nearbyint()` functions round their argument to an integer value in floating-point format, using the current rounding direction (see `fesetround(3)`) and without raising the inexact exception.
>
> The `rint()` functions do the same, but will raise the inexact exception (**`FE_INEXACT`**, checkable via `fetestexcept(3)`) when the result differs in value from the argument.

In other words, `rint` allows you to do error checking while `nearbyint` does not. An example of error-checking:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cfenv>

int main()
{
    std::feclearexcept(FE_INEXACT);
    double a = std::rint(93819.249);
    if (!std::fetestexcept(FE_INEXACT))
        std::cerr << "Bad rounding\n";
    else
        std::cout << a << '\n';
}
```

Comment: The man page makes it sound like it raises FE_INEXACT whenever the argument to rint() isn't already an integral value ("the result differs from the argument"). But presumably it only raises it when the actual floating-point value returned is not exactly equal to the intended integral value due to precision (which does seem to be the case).